# Geofield map : add marker on click listener

Tags: javascript, 9, google-maps

I've added a google map which I feed thanks to the Geofield module.

I'd like to add an onClick event to each marker to have a custom behavior.

this is what I've done this far :

```
  Drupal.behaviors.geofieldGoogleMapInteraction = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (context !== document) {
        return;
      }

      // React on geofieldMapInit event.
      $(document).on('geofieldMapInit', function (e, mapid) {
        var map = Drupal.geoFieldMapFormatter.map_data[mapid].map;
        var markers = Drupal.geoFieldMapFormatter.map_data[mapid].markers;
        map.addMarkerAddedCallback(function(markerClicked) { // is not a function
          triggerClick(markerClicked);
        });

        function triggerClick(markerClicked) {
          console.log("click !")
        }
        $.each(markers, function (storeId, marker) {
          if(parseInt(storeId) !== 56) return;
          const properties = marker.geojsonProperties;
          $(marker).on('click', function() {
            console.log("click") // not triggered
          });
        })
      });
    }
  };
```

I can't manage to trigger the on click of the marker ,I've got nothing in my console. Where am I wrong ?

EDIT : this is the source code of a single marker. I don't see any sign of how the marker id could be retrieved... (I have cluster and single markers at the same time)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If it help someone, this is what I came up with :

```
  $(document).on('geofieldMapInit', function (e, mapid) {
    var map = Drupal.geoFieldMapFormatter.map_data[mapid].map;
    var markers = Drupal.geoFieldMapFormatter.map_data[mapid].markers;

    $.each(markers, function (storeId, marker) {
      const properties = marker.geojsonProperties;
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        console.log('click ' + storeId)
      })
    })
  });
```